# How to migrate chat data from PubNub to getstream-io

Tags: pubnub, getstream-io

How can I migrate my chat data (channels and messages) from PubNub to Getstream-io?
What are the import capabilities with Getstream-io?

I'm currently using PubNub for the live chat in my platform. I'd evaluating to replace it with Getstream-io chat. My current data reside in PubNub's databases.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear you're considering leaving PubNub but we would be happy to help with any questions you have on migrating your data. And we value your insights into your challenges. Our support team can answer your questions if you send us an email at support@pubnub.com.

Comment: You can have the format needed at https://getstream.io/chat/docs/javascript/import/?language=javascript If you contact us at support https://getstream.io/contact/support/ we can help further in your case. We're releasing an open source CLI soon to manage it by yourself too.